# Flex Multiple Textfields?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, builder

I'm trying to create multiple textfields at once with a for loop.
I know in normal flash I can use addChild to add an object on my application. In Flex this does not seem to work. I only get to see one textfield and not more? :(

Here's my code

```
            var Num:uint = int(cmbbox.selectedItem);
            var s:uint=0;
            if(Num<=32) {
                while(Num>0) {
                    var t:TextInput = new TextInput;
                    var nummer:uint;
                    nummer = Num/2;
                    Num = nummer;
                    s++;

                    t.name = "t" + s;
                    t.editable =false;
                    t.graphics.beginFill(45);
                    t.x +=50;
                    trace(Num);
                    loller.alpha=0.2;
                    loller.addElement(t);
                }

            }
```

Hope someone can help :-)

Cheers,

Tom

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason this shouldn't work.  Are you sure that you aren't placing them all at the same X location:

```
// component created w/ default X value of 0
var t:TextInput = new TextInput;
..
// X set to 0 + 50; thus positioning every TextInput at an X position of 50
t.x +=50;
```

---

In case my original answer was unclear, you will have to modify your code in order to position the TextInput's at different locations.  One way to do this is to store theX value and increment it every time through the loop.

```
// create new value 
var xOffSet : Int = 50;

while(Num>0) {
  // component created w/ default X value of 0
  var t:TextInput = new TextInput;
  ..
  // position TextInput
  t.x =xOffset;
  // increment XOffset
  xOffset += 50;
}
```

Comment: Yes I have that in my code and it doesn't seem to work :s
This is what I get http://d.pr/i/dewe

Comment: I know you have that in your code.  And that will place every TextInput at the exact same x position.  ( and since you aren't specifying a Y position, also at the very same Y position ).  Was I unclear in my answer?

Comment: I edited my answer to provide you with a solution instead of just pointing out the error.

Comment: In that case, be sure to select the this as a formal answer to the question.